# Почему при position absolute при top: 0; right: 0; картинка улетает на самый вверх. Где я допустил ошибку

Tags: css3, html5

```css
.section__three-title{
color: #01353E;
font-family: Raleway;
font-size: 40px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: normal;
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
/* padding-bottom: 100px; */
}

.section__subtitle-text{
color: #242121;
font-family: Roboto Condensed;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 18px; /* 128.571% */
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.section__inner{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: row;
width: 50%;
flex-wrap: wrap;

}


.section__inner-item{
padding-bottom: 30px;


}

.photo{
width: 60%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section__three">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="section__three-title" >ПОКОРЯЙ ВЕРШИНЫ <span>/</span></h3>
    <div class="section__inner">
      <div class="section__inner-item">
      <p class="section__subtitle">Преподаватели нашей школы серфинга в числе лучших серферов на Канарских островах. Среди них - чемпион Европы по лонгборду, который с радостью поделится опытом как с новичками, так и более опытными серферами. 
        Все члены преподавательского состава являются сертифицированными членами Федерации серфинга Канарских островов. Некоторые из них знают русский язык, что определенно позиционирует нас как русскую школу серфинга за границей!</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="section__inner-item">
        <p class="section__subtitle">Весь тренерский состав регулярно участвует в семинарах и курсах повышения квалификации, которые проводятся по всему миру различными известными серф-клубами и федерациями. Поэтому в нашей школе серфинга вы можете быть спокойны: вас обучают лучшие тренеры!</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="section__inner-item">
          <p class="section__subtitle">Методика обучения серфингу рассчитана как на новичков, на серферов среднего уровня, так и на серферов уровня ТОП. Тренеры находят подход к каждому, несмотря на то, что обучение серфингу в нашей школе производится в группах. Однако, мы предлагаем персональные уроки серфинга - только вы и тренер! П</p>
          </div>

          <div class="photo">
          <img src="image/photo.jpg" alt="">
           </div>

    </div>
    

  </div>
  
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Блок, относительно которого делаете отсчёт позиции, должен имет значение position.

Comment: Абсолютно позиционированный блок позиционируется относительно ближайшего родителя с `position` отличной от `static`. Если такового не находится - позиционирование выполняется относительно доrумента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы задаёте position:absolute какому-то блоку, то ему надо позиционироваться относительно чего-то. Чтобы это сделать, нужно обёртке (относительно которой, подразумевается позиционирование) задать position:relative